# No module named 'sqlalchemy'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

There's an issue with `from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship`, when I try to run my app with that import, `ModuleNotFoundError` is raised and it says `No module named 'sqlalchemy'`.

But when I delete the `from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship`, I can run my app well with no issue whatsoever. Am I missing a module or something?

Other imports from sqlalchemy seems to run smoothly, e.g

`from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Boolean, ForeignKey`

**I'm using SQLAlchemy-1.3.22 and I installed sqlalchemy by using the command pip3 install sqlalchemy**

**Here's my requirements.txt**

```
APScheduler==3.6.3
certifi==2020.12.5
cffi==1.14.4
cryptography==3.2.1
decorator==4.4.2
mysqlclient==2.0.2
pycparser==2.20
PyMySQL==0.10.1
python-dotenv==0.15.0
python-telegram-bot==13.1
pytz==2020.4
six==1.15.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.22
SQLAlchemy-ImageAttach==1.1.0
tornado==6.1
tzlocal==2.1
Wand==0.6.5
```

Comment: It's probably an issue with the way you've installed SQLAlchemy. Can you add your installation details here? Check if you are running your code in the same virtual environment where you installed it.

Comment: I tried reinstaling by doing pip3 uninstall sqlalchemy and pip3 install sqlalchemy, to no avail

Comment: Create a new file `foo.py` and insert the following: `import sys; print(sys.version)` --> what do you see when you run this?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I tried reinstalling the package and also rewrote my entire code. The import works now!